# Why if part not executed in laravel 5 controller method?

Tags: laravel-5

```
public function index1()
{




    $g = Request::Input('grade');
    $s = Request::Input('subject');

    if(strcmp($g,'Select A Grade')==0 || strcmp($s,'Select A Subject')==0) {

        if (strcmp($s, 'Select A Subject') == 0) {
            // Session::flash('msg', 'Please select the Subject.');
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();

        } else if (strcmp($g, 'Select A Grade') == 0) {
            // Session::flash('msg', 'Please select the Grade.');
            return redirect()->back()->withInput();

        }


    }

else{

        $u = DB::table('upldtbls')->where('grade',$g)->where('subject',$s)->get();


        return view('2Eng',compact('u'));
}

}
```

Above is the controller method. Main else part executed correctly. But main if part not executed as I wanted. In main if condition I want to stay on the same page if drop box values are equal to that which means when they haven't select an option from drop box. Can any one figure out this mess?

```
{!! Form::select('Select A Grade', array('' => 'Select A Grade','2' => '2', '3' => '3','4' => '4'), 'Select A Grade', ['class' => 'form-control'])
{!! Form::select('Select A Subject', array('' => 'Select A Subject','English' => 'English', 'Mathematics' => 'Mathematics','Environmental Studies' => 'Environmental Studies'), 'Select A Subject', ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `if` part is probably not being executed because the condition is not being met. Check that `$g` or `$s` is equal to `0` as per you check. If you are simply trying to see if these Input parameters are empty / blank, amend your `if` statement to:

```
if(!$g || !$s){
...
}
```

Also, you should really use `Request::Input` instead of `$_GET`, but you need to fix it to one of the below:

```
# Laravel 5.1.x or earlier
$g = Request::Input('grade');
$s = Request::Input('subject');
```

or

```
# Laravel 5.2.x or later
$g = $request->input('grade');
$s = $request->input('subject');
```

---

**UPDATE**

The issue is with your `select` boxes. You have incorrectly named them, and you would have noticed this if you carried out some basic debugging. Update them as follows:

```
{!! Form::select('grade', array('' => 'Select A Grade','2' => '2', '3' => '3','4' => '4'), null, ['class' => 'form-control'])
{!! Form::select('subject', array('' => 'Select A Subject','English' => 'English', 'Mathematics' => 'Mathematics','Environmental Studies' => 'Environmental Studies'), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

i.e. the first parameter should be the `name` of the field, which gets passed to `$_GET`. After updating the form, please update the `if` statement to my suggestion above.

Comment: Have you verified that the condition is being met first? Do this by checking the value of `$g` and `$s` before the `if` statement to see what your code returns.

Comment: Oh!. you are correct. It doesn't take values if it is not selected any value from drop box. Why is that?

Comment: Now the issue is clear. Answer has been updated. Please update the code for your `select` boxes.